# JPA, генерация первичного ключа

Tags: java-ee, orm, jpa, ejb, persistance

Доброго времени суток. Пишу на бинах свое небольшое приложение.
Появилась проблема с генерацией первичного ключа. ( при добавлении данных приложение не падает,ошибок в логах нет. )
После развертывания приложения на сервере, первый merge проходит без проблем,запись появляется в таблице. После повторного добавления данных, данные не добавляются в таблицу.
Добавил в вывод логов sql-запросы,наткнулся на интересные строчки :

Лог при вставки первой записи:

```
   [2015-02-07T22:40:03.471+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1423338003471] [levelValue: 800] [[
      [EL Fine]: sql: 2015-02-07 22:40:03.471--ClientSession(1512774189)--Connection(843240395)--INSERT INTO PROMOTER (id_promoter, area_of_residence, contact_phone, date_of_employment, EMAIL, experience_working, fname_promoter, form_of_education, link_to_a_profile_in_social_networks, name_promoter, study_place) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

При вставке второй записи

```
[2015-02-07T22:40:18.153+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1423338018153] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2015-02-07 22:40:18.153--ClientSession(1512774189)--Connection(843240395)--UPDATE PROMOTER SET area_of_residence = ?, contact_phone = ?, EMAIL = ?, experience_working = ?, fname_promoter = ?, link_to_a_profile_in_social_networks = ?, study_place = ? WHERE (id_promoter = ?)
    bind => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

Даже если удалить все записи из таблицы,оставив её пустой, в логах будет выводиться такое же сообщение,какое и выводилось при вставке второй записи. 
Тут вот и непонятно : если данных нет в таблице, почему при мерже (merge) происходит апдейт (какой-то записи) ,а не добавление.
Если присвоить значения идентификатору вручную,все прекрасно работает.
Часть Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Promoter.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Promoter p")
public class Promoter implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_promoter")
    private int idPromoter;

    //Остальная часть кода

}
```

Часть бина

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PromoterBean {

    private EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Local")
        .createEntityManager();

    public PromoterBean() {
    }

    public void addPromoter(Promoter promoter) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(promoter);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destruct() {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

persistence

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="Local" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>project_manager_entity.Promoter</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="**" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

Таблица создана в Mysql средствами JPA? Если да то попробуйте вместо Identity Seqcuence. Если таблица создана в Mysql, то id_promoter не стоит ли галочка auto_increment.